# SQL query to fetch output based on multiple row values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with sample data as follows

```
-----------------------------
UserID   | ScreenID | rights |
------------------------------
 admin        22         0
 admin        23         0
 admin        24         0

 userA        22         1
 userA        23         1
 userA        24         1

 userB        22         0
 userB        23         0
 userB        24         1
```

Now I want to fetch 'UserID' and 'rights' details as follows:
     For each user 
  if the "rights" for all the ScreenIDs are same then that rights value (either '0' or '1')
  else rights value as 2

That means, required output from the above table should be:

```
admin , 0
userA , 1
userB  ,2
```

Please help me in writing SQL query for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (untested on sqlserver):

```
select userid
     , case when min(rights) = max(rights) 
            then min(rights) 
            else 2 
       end 
from t 
group by userid
```

Answer (score 5):

With a cte or derived table which does a `GROUP BY` on `UserId`, you can then tell whether all `Rights` are the same:

```
SELECT UserID,
       CASE 
          WHEN minR = maxR THEN minR
          ELSE 2
       END AS Result
FROM
(
  SELECT UserID, MIN(Rights) as minR, MAX(Rights) as maxR
  FROM UserRights
  GROUP BY UserID
) x;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59337/9)